# How do I create multi array?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I create multi array?

Have suck a code; which is two cycles

```
boolean pabaiga_ciklo = false;
while (!pabaiga_ciklo) 
{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Suma. When result: " + V);


    for (int i=2; i<257; i=i*2 )
    {
          V = i+V;              
          System.out.println("Suma: " + V + " when added:: " + i);  
    } 


    V = (int) ((Math.PI * Math.pow(H, 4) * (Math.pow(R, 2)
            + Math.pow(r, 2) + Math.pow(r, 5) * Math.pow(r, 3))) / 3);


    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("subtraction. With result: " + V);
    for (int i=2; i<257; i=i*2 )
    {
          V = V-i;
          System.out.println("Suma: " +V+ " when subtracted: "+i);
    }     
}
```

with folowing results showed in console; (everything is inputted by me)

```
Add. When result: 50
Sum: 52 when added: 2
Suma: 56 when added: 4
Suma: 64 when added: 8
Suma: 80 when added: 16
Suma: 112 when added: 32
Suma: 176 when added: 64
Suma: 304 when added: 128
Suma: 560 when added: 256

subtraction. With result: 50
Suma: 48 when subtracted: 2
Suma: 44 when subtracted: 4
Suma: 36 when subtracted: 8
Suma: 20 when subtracted: 16
Suma: -12 when subtracted: 32
Suma: -76 when subtracted: 64
Suma: -204 when subtracted: 128
Suma: -460 when subtracted: 256
```

I need to create an array X[8][16] where values should be suma:

```
    sum when Added                  sum when  subtracted
1.   52 56 64 80 112 176 304 560  || 48 44 36 20 -12 -76 -204 -460
2.   0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0       0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0 
..........
8.   0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0       0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0
```

How to add them?

Comment: I'm confused, do you just want to know hot to make a multi-array in java, or do you want to know how to integrate it with your code?

Comment: "Have suck a tutorial" on creating multidimensional arrays: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/java-use-arrays-with-two-dimensions-or-more.html ;) Basically, create an array and fill in while you're displaying your calculations

Comment: perhaps how to integrate it with my code
i whant to know how fill an array with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solution fits what you need as your code and your request is not very clear to me.

```
boolean pabaiga_ciklo = false;
int [ ] [ ] matrix = new double [ 8 ] [ 16 ] ;
while (!pabaiga_ciklo) 
{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Suma. When result: " + V);

    int row = 0;
    for (int i=2; i<257; i=i*2 )
    {
          V = i+V;              
          System.out.println("Suma: " + V + " when added:: " + i);  
          matrix[0][row] = V;
          row++;
    } 


    V = (int) ((Math.PI * Math.pow(H, 4) * (Math.pow(R, 2)
            + Math.pow(r, 2) + Math.pow(r, 5) * Math.pow(r, 3))) / 3);


    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("subtraction. With result: " + V);
    row = 8;
    for (int i=2; i<257; i=i*2 )
    {
          V = V-i;
          System.out.println("Suma: " +V+ " when subtracted: "+i);
          matrix[0][row] = V;
          row++;
    }     
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: and where  should write sytemout>?
it should show me mine array

Comment: I just edited my answer. The last block of code prints the matrix using System.out.

Comment: Did my answer helped at least a bit?